# Do I need "| xargs -n 1" to get around xargs' -I side-effect?

Tags: xargs, arguments, newlines

I was suprised to discover this:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 echo
1
2
3
4
5

$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 -I FOO echo FOO
1 2 3 4 5
```

That is, using the `-I` flag has this side effect:

> Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.

So the workaround I see is:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 | xargs -n 1 -I FOO echo FOO
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there a better workaround?

My actual command line looks like this:

```
echo 102DRIFT 103DRIFT 104DRIFT 105DRIFT | xargs -n 1 | xargs -n 1 -I _DIR_ python process.py /SDcard/DCIM/_DIR_/ MyTrace.gpx 10
```

(Ubuntu Trusty if relevant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [GNU xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html), you can use `-d` option:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 -d" " -I FOO echo FOO
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `xargs` at all:

```
for DCIM in /SDcard/DCIM/10[2-5]DRIFT/
do  python process.py "$DCIM" MyTrace.gpx 10
done
```

Still, there are a couple of other things you might do besides:

```
printf 10%dDRIFT\\n 2 3 4 5 | ...the rest...
```

Or, if you don't have any quotes in input anyway...

```
IN | tr \  \\n | xargs ... the rest ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately
`echo 1 2 3 4 5 | xargs -n 1 -d" " -I FOO echo FOO` from cuonglm's answer
somehow creates one more empty line and executes command 6 times instead of 5.

My solution is to use the following workaround:

`echo 1 2 3 4 5 | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I FOO echo FOO`